# C# Winforms Authenticate with Microsoft Onedrive

Tags: c#, server, oauth-2.0, onedrive

Is is possible to login to Microsoft's OneDrive API without having to use a Browser-based OAuth mechanism?

I have a server application in C# that I would like to connect to a OneDrive account and manage files.  Every code sample and piece of information I find always requires a browser-based authentication process.  Is there way to utilize the Application secure keys or password to bypass this nuisance?

-Jeff

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that with application identity (no user login is needed).

Here are the steps that you have to do in your Azure portal:

1. Register Application in azure portal
2. Add required scopes like `Files.ReadWrite.All` etc..
3. Generate secrete Key for Identity

Or here is a [Shortcut](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start) provided by MS Docs, where  you can create **Client Id** and **Secret** with a single click.

[image]

Use **Client ID**, **Tenant Id**, **Secret Key** to authenticate any calls without user login.